# is this bar too fast for a piano composition? (3/4 time) How can I improve my piece?

Tags: piano, composition

I have only started to make new pieces and im not quite sure if this sounds nice 
[image: picture of a bar of the bass in my compoition]

[image]

Here is the first page...i want to make the first half should fast and ecstatic juxtaposed with the sad and slow second half. How to improve it?

Comment: Hi musik7. This isn't the kind of question we answer on the main site. However, once you've gained 20 reputation points, you can post this in our chat room, [The Auditorium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126233/the-auditorium), which is intended for giving feedback on compositions.

Comment: im kinda helpless

Comment: Welcome! Please read about [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Meanwhile, these notes could be any speed; it depends on the tempo of the beat.

Comment: Starting at m. 23 there is an accidental `C#`, but `C#` sharp is already in the key signature. Am I missing something, why is the accidental used?

Answer (score 0):

> is this bar too fast for a piano composition? ... fast and ecstatic

You really should describe the tempo in beats per minute (bpm), metronome speeds, because "fast" is too subjective. It could cover a really wide range of tempos.

Assuming you aren't a pianist, you should learn some basic piano skills, try to play passages yourself, and then make the notation as clear as possible for executing what the hands do. Don't just dump notes into software, click play, and then expect someone will actually be able to play it. Give some consideration what you're asking real hands to do. At the very least, if you really hope someone will play your music, try to make it as playable as possible.

I think some changes like this might help...

[image]

- Tempo marking tells me the expected speed
- `LH` and `RH` tell me what hands to use, `LH` is left hand, `RH` is right hand
- Stem direction up and down also tell me what hands to use, stems up are right hand, stems down are left hand
- The `./.` mark in the second and fourth bars means 'repeat the previous bar' and cuts down on ink and clutter, and makes repetitive passage much more instantly readable

Maybe you don't need to use all those markings, but it provides an example of things to consider for notation.

> ...not quite sure if this sounds nice

"Sounds nice" is too vague to say much. I played the first few bars, and it sounds fine. It's all diatonic, mostly outlining triads and perfect fifths. Let's call that "resonant" to be a bit more objective. It features two minor triads, but it isn't minor key, there is no leading one, so it has a sort of *modal* flavor. "Modal" is also a bit more objective. The tempo at 120 bpm could be given the traditional indication of *allegro*, which is a basic fast tempo, and IMO not too hard to play, a good player could play faster. When you bring in two notes at once, those are off the strong beat and so we call them *syncopated*, and syncopated rhythms and described as exciting or energetic. That give us an objective description regarding tempo and rhythm.

Now that we have a little bit of objective analysis of what you wrote I think we can drop the question about "sounds nice" and say the musical characteristics are in line with your intended effect of "fast and ecstatic."

This piece by Erik Satie might give you some idea of what a really good pianist can play: *[Embryons desséchés, III. De Podophthalma](https://youtu.be/rzuWmVaUoFw?t=293)* (includes score). It probably isn't the mood you're aiming for, but it does start with a rolled chord ending on the up beat which is similar to the rhythm you are using. Also, the piece starts out very energetic, but in the middle is changes to a calmer mood, and that's sort of the design you describe. Again, Satie might not be a match for the mood you want, he was very eccentric, but the piece can give you some idea about the *technical performance skills* of a good pianist.

Answer (score 0):

Too fast?  We don't know.  You haven't specified a tempo.  But it's not technically all that difficult.   The pianist might decide to take some nots in the right hand.  It's fine to leave this to the player, it's equally fine to make some suggestions in the notation.

Close positing chords in that register can sound muddy. Play it (or let your notation program play it).   Be critical.  Do you want a flat dynamic (WHAT dynamic? You don't specify one) throughout or would some crescendos and diminuendos be effective?   Do you want the notes detached or legato?

Etc.  etc.  Some detail can raise this sort of writing above the criticism of being mere 'sewing machine' music.